# How to create a javascript object from java list without using any libraries

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

Java Code:

```
List<User> user_list = getAllUsers(); //Code to get all the users from some service
List<String> usersOfGroup = null;
for (int i=0; i<user_list.size(); i++) {
  usersOfGroup.add("'"+user_list.get(i).getContactId()+"':'"+user_list.get(i).getFullName()+"'}");
}
pageContext.setAttribute("usersList", usersOfGroup);
```

Desired output in jsp:

```
var titles = [{'58512':'John Smith'},
              {'58513':'Adam Gallagher'},
              {'58514':'Geoffrey Peer'},
              {'58515':'Sansa Stark'},
              {'58516':'Tyrion Lannister'},
              {'58517':'Saul Goodman'},
              {'58518':'Walt Whitman'}];
```

I tried creating an array instead of the arraylist but it doesn't render on the jsp using - `"<%=usersList%>"`

Should i create an array list or an array or something else in java that i can retrieve in javascript? What should be I be adding as I am pretty sure `"{'"+user_list.get(i).getContactId()+"':'"+user_list.get(i).getFullName()+"'}"` is not the correct way to do it.

If needed, I want to create a javascript function to output it in desired format instead of using json/gson etc.

Edit:
The javascript array needs to be fed into:

```
$.each(titles, function(){
            $.each(this, function (name, value) {
              var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                "text": value,
                "value": name
            });
            if(data === value){
                $option.attr("selected", "selected")
            }
            $select.append($option);
           });
        });
```

Comment: What does it render?

Comment: You're missing an opening brace (`{`).

Comment: Why are you avoiding "any libraries"?

Comment: If you're going to manually construct the individual items as strings (which I don't recommend) you might as well just append to a `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` rather than using a `List<String>`. Note that a user's name might include an apostrophe, which would need to be escaped if your desired output uses single quotes.

Comment: @shmosel It does render the expected value as a string But when i assign it to a variable or pass it as it is into the $.each function, it doesn't take it. It does take the hardcoded var "titles" and renders the select properly

Comment: @nnnnnn That's a good suggestion but either way the string is not working when passed to the $.each fuction

Comment: Why are you using nested $.each loops? You only need one loop. Your question shows the desired output, but what is the actual output if you use the browser's "view source" option?

Comment: @nnnnn the var titles is a hardcoded array, which when passed to the $.each function, works as desired. The string that i am generating (from the list) looks the same as the var title when i print it in the console but the $.each function breaks when i pass that string to it.